# BATCH ONLY: Moving files based on creation date within a FOR loop

Tags: batch-file, pdf, for-loop, cmd, set

Beginner Code Warning:

I have a folder with PDF's based on multiple masks

ex: `*-*-*.pdf`

I am trying to create a directory based on the file name and then move the file into a month folder based on the creation date within that directory

ex:

```
%source%\%%a-%%b-%%c.pdf
%destination%\%%a\%%b\%month%\%%a-%%b-%%c.pdf
```

Here is the code that i have so far, in it i am using ( dir /t:c *.pdf ) to grab the month

```
@ECHO OFF
title Invoice/Packslip Mover
::mode con: cols=16 lines=8

SETLOCAL

:Top

cls
move C:\customers\Test\invoice\*.pdf  "C:\customers\Test\invoice-temp" >nul 2>&1


:Invoice1
::   *-*-*.pdf
SET "source=C:\customers\Test\invoice-temp"
SET "destination=C:\customers\Test\cloud\customers\invoice"
PUSHD %source%
FOR /f "tokens=1-3 delims=-" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "*-*-*.pdf"'
 ) DO ( 
 dir /t:c *.pdf | find "%%a-%%b-%%c">test.txt
 FINDSTR "07/*/* " test.txt
 IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 SET month=July
 echo %month%
 pause
 mkdir "%destination%\%%a\%%b\%month%" >nul 2>&1
 MOVE /Y "%%a-%%b-%%c" "%destination%\%%a\%%b\%month%" >nul 2>&1
)
POPD
```

When performing the following statement:

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 SET month=July
echo %month%
```

it will not echo the variable July, even though the error level is returned

This is just one way i could think to get the creation date and save it as a value

I am open to any other methods within in vanilla CMD to solve this issue

Comment: Can you add some more information on what is going wrong with your script? Does it error?

Comment: @에이바 Thank you for looking this over, i have added a little more to the bottom of my Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set setlocal enableDelayedExpansion.

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

FOR /f "tokens=1-3 delims=-" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "*-*-*.pdf"'
 ) DO ( 
 dir /t:c *.pdf | find "%%a-%%b-%%c">test.txt
 FINDSTR "07/*/* " test.txt
 IF !ERRORLEVEL! EQU 0 SET month=July
 echo !month!
 pause
 mkdir "%destination%\%%a\%%b\!month!" >nul 2>&1
 MOVE /Y "%%a-%%b-%%c" "%destination%\%%a\%%b\!month!" >nul 2>&1
)
```

This worked for me, however, you probably want to achieve this:

```
FOR /f "tokens=1-3 delims=-" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "*-*-*.pdf"'
 ) DO ( 
 dir /t:w *.pdf | find "%%a-%%b-%%c">test.txt
 FINDSTR "07/*/* " test.txt
 IF !ERRORLEVEL! EQU 0 (
  SET month=July
  echo !month!
  pause
  mkdir "%destination%\%%a\%%b\!month!" >nul 2>&1
  MOVE /Y "%%a-%%b-%%c" "%destination%\%%a\%%b\!month!" >nul 2>&1
 )
)
```

Comment: I gave this a try but when I use "DO CALL" the FIND command will not export the string into a txt file.  I also used enableDelayedExpansion but the errorlevel is not being retrieved

Comment: Did you try doubling the percent signs (%%errorlevele%% and %%month%%)?

Comment: I edited my answer and it should work now (it worked for me).

Comment: You sir are amazing... this is exactly what i needed. can you explain the difference between ! and % please

Comment: Thanks! Look [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/variableexpansion.php) for an explanation.